# How to use Image widget correctly in kivy python

Tags: python, image, user-interface, kivy, widget

I wanted to open an image using:

```
self.bl.add_widget(Image(source = 'D:\\test\\1.png', pos = [0, 0]))
```

But if this line is almost at the very end of the code, then the image opens completely black. But if this line is almost at the very beginning, then the image opens correctly. I'm confused, I don't understand why this is happening. Can anyone explain this to me? How can I fix this? For example, I wrote the correct image opening code:

```
 from kivy.app import App 
 from kivy.uix.image import Image
 
 class TestApp(App):
     def build(self):
         return Image(source = 'D:\\test\\1.png', pos = [0, 0])
 
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     TestApp().run()
```

Comment: For reference, I don't use .kv files or builder

Comment: I noticed that the images do not open correctly if I open them through a function opened with threading